# js canvas object movement animation using pythagorean theorem

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am trying to make an object move to click position, like in rpgs like diablo or modern moba games, i needed to find a way to animate to click coordinates and i have found a method that uses pythagorean theorem, i understood and custimized the code to a certain degree, but there is a bug where the ball keeps bouncing in the very end of animation. I know this happens because of the "moves" variable and the loop, but can't understand exactly why.

here's the function that draws the object

```
function drawPlayer() {
    //
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, 12, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    
    //Calculate variables
    let dx = player.newx - player.x;
    let dy = player.newy - player.y;
    let distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    let moves = distance/player.speed;
    let xunits = (player.newx - player.x)/moves;
    let yunits = (player.newy - player.y)/moves;

    if (moves > 0 ) {
        moves--;
        player.x += xunits;
        player.y += yunits;
        console.log(moves);
    }
}
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
  setClickCoords(e);
  drawPlayer();

})
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

const player = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  newx: 0,
  newy: 0,
  speed: 1,
  radius: 15,
}

function drawPlayer() {
  //Draw 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Calculate variables
  let dx = player.newx - player.x;
  let dy = player.newy - player.y;
  let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  let moves = distance / player.speed;
  let xunits = (player.newx - player.x) / moves;
  let yunits = (player.newy - player.y) / moves;

  console.log(moves);

  if (moves > 0) {
    moves--;
    player.x += xunits;
    player.y += yunits;
    console.log(moves);
  }
}

function setClickCoords(e) {

  player.newx = e.offsetX;
  player.newy = e.offsetY;
  document.getElementById('oldcoords').innerHTML = "old Coords " + player.x + " " + player.y;
  document.getElementById('newcoords').innerHTML = "new Coords " + player.newx + " " + player.newy;
}


function gameLoop() {
  window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 24);
  drawPlayer()
}

gameLoop();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#canvas1 {
  border: 3px solid white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#oldcoords,
#newcoords {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<span id="oldcoords"></span>
<span id="newcoords"></span>

<canvas id="canvas1"> </canvas>
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Comment: im srorry i forgot to paste the link to it

https://jsfiddle.net/gdk5eo62/3/

Comment: I'm not sure if it will have an effect somewhere else in the code, but `if (moves > 1)` in `drawPlayer` would stop the ball.

Comment: Check if `moves` is between 0 and 1. If it's between, move the ball to the desired position. Currently, the ball goes too far in the direction and has to return in the next animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `moves` is between 0 and 1. If it's between, move the ball to the desired position. Currently, the ball goes too far in the direction and has to return in the next animation.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
  setClickCoords(e);
  drawPlayer();

})
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

const player = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  newx: 0,
  newy: 0,
  speed: 1,
  radius: 15,
}

function drawPlayer() {
  //Draw 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Calculate variables
  let dx = player.newx - player.x;
  let dy = player.newy - player.y;
  let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  let moves = distance / player.speed;

  console.log(moves);

  if (moves > 1) {
    let xunits = (player.newx - player.x) / moves;
    let yunits = (player.newy - player.y) / moves;
    moves--;
    player.x += xunits;
    player.y += yunits;
    console.log(moves);
  } else if (moves > 0) {
    moves = 0;
    player.x = player.newx;
    player.y = player.newy;
    console.log(moves);
  }
}

function setClickCoords(e) {

  player.newx = e.offsetX;
  player.newy = e.offsetY;
  document.getElementById('oldcoords').innerHTML = "old Coords " + player.x + " " + player.y;
  document.getElementById('newcoords').innerHTML = "new Coords " + player.newx + " " + player.newy;
}


function gameLoop() {
  window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 24);
  drawPlayer()
}

gameLoop();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#canvas1 {
  border: 3px solid white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#oldcoords,
#newcoords {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<span id="oldcoords"></span>
<span id="newcoords"></span>

<canvas id="canvas1"> </canvas>
```

Comment: I did try this, but it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @freemanfl What do you mean, it didn't work? You can click "Run code snippet" in my answer and see that it works.

Comment: yes, actually it does, it was me having problem with live server, thank you a lot for help!